# VXLAN with unicast only transport?

Tags: vlan, unicast

I started looking into VXLAN recently and I am trying to grasp the basic concepts of it. The standard use of VXLAN transport appears to be multicast, however many ISPs do not allow multicast traffic. Is it possible to implement unicast only VXLAN for example between R1 at dc1 and R2 at dc2 without any third party controllers?

Answer (score 0):

VXLAN provides L2 transport, you can use it for unicast, multicast, even broadcast. The exact point of VXLAN is to provide a large number of L2 tunnels from one location to another, possibly remote one.

Answer (score 0):

VXLAN sure could be used in unicast mode
There are some drawbacks presents but this mode is fully functional

This article provides great examples of unicast VXLAN configurations: https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2017-vxlan-linux#without-multicast

When using VXLAN to connect datacenters via public internet networks make sure to use encryption. IPSec or Wireguard will be a good choice for IP-level security.